# Maven "Update Project" operation in Eclipse results in PMD "unable to find referenced rule" error

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I have a Maven project imported into Eclipse via m2e. The project includes Spring and other dependencies, but for some reason they are not being recognized by Eclipse at all. When I attempt to use "Update Project..." (right click => Maven => Update Project) to rectify the issue, I get the following error:

An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project".
Unable to find referenced rule EmptyIfStmt; perhaps the rule name is misspelled?

PMD and Checkstyle are not enabled for this project. Any ideas as to why I might be getting the error and/or how to address it?

The project builds fine via "mvn clean install," so I assume that this issue is Eclipse-specific.

I've tried disabling and re-enabling the Maven nature of the project but to no avail. I end up getting the same error upon converting the project back to a Maven one.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project folder and run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` before running `Update Project`. I hope it will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The maven-eclipse-plugin (used in mvn eclipse:eclipse) is discontinued and shouldn't be used anymore. M2Eclipse replaces it for most, if not all, usage.